# sed command to process the input stream and convert each occurrence of the word

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i need help with my code.
i need to write a sed command to process the input stream and convert each occurrence of the word "page" followed by a number to an HTML hyperlink of the form , where NNN is the page number.

For example:

```
See page 107
```

should be replaced by:

```
See <a href="#p107">page 107</a>
```

the code should be POSIX compliant:

```
sed -r 's/________/_______/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex which uses POSIX notation,

```
(page[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+))
```

And replace it with this,

```
<a href="#p\2">\1</a>
```

Try with this sample command,

```
echo "See page 107" | sed -r 's~(page[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+))~<a href="#p\2">\1</a>~g'
```

Or use -E instead of -r (for OS X)

```
echo "See page 107" | sed -E 's~(page[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+))~<a href="#p\2">\1</a>~g'
```

Which gives this output,

```
See <a href="#p107">page 107</a>
```

Comment: @MottiCohen: Can you tell what didn't work and how are you trying with what command? May be I should be able to help if you are not doing something right.

Comment: Glad to help :)